# Horizontal line through table cell

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, rules

I have a very long, thin table that I'm folding onto itself to make a wider, shorter version.  The table has a couple horizontal rules to separate data categories.  For example, the original table is like:

```
-----------------------
| Column A | Column B |
-----------------------
| Data A1  | Data B1  |
| Data A2  | Data B2  |
| ------------------- |
| Data A3  | Data B3  |
...
```

and I'm wanting it like:

```
---------------------------------------------------
| Column A | Column B |     | Column A | Column B |
---------------------------------------------------
| Data A1  | Data B1  |     | Data A51 | Data B51 |
| Data A2  | Data B2  |     | Data A52 | Data B52 |
| ------------------- |     | Data A53 | Data B53 |
| Data A3  | Data B3  |     | Data A54 | Data B54 |
...
```

The problem is I cannot get the desired behavior with the horizontal rules.  If I use something like `\cmidrule{1-2}`, there is a blank row in the right two columns:

```
---------------------------------------------------
| Column A | Column B |     | Column A | Column B |
---------------------------------------------------
| Data A1  | Data B1  |     | Data A51 | Data B51 |
| Data A2  | Data B2  |     | Data A52 | Data B52 |
| -------------------                             |
| Data A3  | Data B3  |     | Data A53 | Data B53 |
...
```

I've tried playing with `\vspace{-3mm}` but I can't find values and a placement that gets the right results.  I've also considered not using `\cmidrule` and fill the left two cells with a horizontal line.  Something like

```
\multicolumn{2}{c}{--------} & Data A53 & Data B53 \\
```

However, I can't figure out how to make this horizontal line.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`) or hit Ctrl+K.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `\hrulefill` in place of your `----` (but the vertical spacing may be rather strange, compared to `\cmidrule`)  or you could use `\cline{1-2}` which will open up a gap in the other columns.  Or (perhaps simplest) you could just use two separate tabular environments side by side.

If  you want to control the vertical position of the rule you can use `\leaders` for example

```
\leaders\hbox{\rule[0.4em]{.1pt}{0.4pt}}\hfill\mbox{}
```

The `\mbox{}` is needed to protect the leaders from `\unskip` which the tabular code adds to remove white space from the end of the entry.

Comment: Thanks.  Your tip about \hrulefill was close to working for me, but your were right about the vertical spacing being off.  It led me to discover `\rule` which I use as `\multicolmn{2}{l}{\rule[0.4em]{7.4cm}{0.4pt}}`.  The only downside is I have to find the right width manually.  It'd be nice to find a way for this to automatically fill the multicolumn.

Comment: @drs `\leaders\hbox{\rule[0.4em]{.1pt}{0.4pt}}\hfill`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in a table cell. When wrapping with \leaders\hbox ... \hfill, the rule isn't drawn at all.

Comment: @drs sorry you need to protect it from `\unskip` use: `\leaders\hbox{\rule[0.4em]{.1pt}{0.4pt}}\hfill\mbox{}`

Comment: Yes, this worked perfectly.  If you want to modify you're answer with this instruction, I'll accept it.  For reference, the full commands look like: `\multicolumn{2}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}c@{\hskip 1cm}}{\leaders\hbox{\rule[0.2em]{.1pt}{0.4pt}}\hfill\mbox{}}` for rules in the left two columns and `\multicolumn{2}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}c}{\leaders\hbox{\rule[0.2em]{.1pt}{0.4pt}}\hfill\mbox{}}` for rules in the right two columns.  The `\extracolsep`s and `\hskip`s are necessarily because I have extra spacing between the 2nd and 3rd columns of the table.

Comment: Is it possible to make a minimal working example of this? I pasted the two suggestions [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGyYw.png) but they resulted in absolutely nothing when compiled (surely these must be within a table, but it doesn't seem possible to see the code working in action without an actual table there).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Is it not possible for you to make a "minimum working example"? A reader can make a table, but how are they supposed to know if they're doing it right? Does the question or answer even mention anything about using `p` rather than `c`? In the following table `\begin{tabular}{ p p p }
  \multicolumn{2}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}c@{\hskip 1cm}}{\leaders\hbox{\rule[0.2em]{.1pt}{0.4pt}}\hfill\mbox{}}  & 3 \\
  4 & 5 & 6 \\
  7 & 8 & 9 \\
\end{tabular}` the effect of the `\multicolumn{2}` part is not clear in the output.